# How to join three data source?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a query something like this:

```
SELECT a.shop_id,
         a.product_id,
         a.position,
         b.category_id
FROM X AS a
JOIN Y AS b
    ON a.product_id = CAST(b.id AS bigint)
WHERE site_id = 1
GROUP BY  a.shop_id, a.product_id, b.category_id, a.position
```

Now, I want to get one more variable (book_name) from Z data source. To do this, I should join the Z data source with the above query by doing this:

```
JOIN Z AS c
    ON a.product_id = CAST(c.id AS bigint)
```

But I don't know where I should put it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: _I don't know where I should put it..._ What do you mean? You already have a JOIN statement in your query. What is stopping you to add another one?

Comment: You do know that you can have more than one join in a sql query..don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it with other join statements and fetch book_name from `c` -

```
SELECT a.shop_id,
         a.product_id,
         a.position,
         b.category_id,
         c.book_name
FROM X AS a
JOIN Y AS b
    ON a.product_id = CAST(b.id AS bigint)
JOIN Z AS c
    ON a.product_id = CAST(c.id AS bigint)
WHERE site_id = 1
GROUP BY  a.shop_id, a.product_id, b.category_id, a.position
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always place all joins after the **FROM** clause. One after the other.

```
SELECT a.shop_id,
         a.product_id,
         a.position,
         b.category_id,
         c.book_name
FROM X AS a
JOIN Y AS b
    ON a.product_id = CAST(b.id AS bigint)
JOIN Z AS c
    ON a.product_id = CAST(c.id AS bigint)
WHERE site_id = 1
GROUP BY  a.shop_id, a.product_id, b.category_id, a.position
```

Also, remember there are different types of joins. In this case you are using an **inner join** which will return all the records from the 3 tables where the join condition is met.

Please, find this useful link, in case you want to read a little bit more about other types of joins. I found it very handy.

[SQL Join Types](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types)

Hope this help!